# How does Spring Batch define multiple jobs execution order in Spring boot app?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I tried to search the spring batch documentation how Spring defines the execution order of multiple batch jobs, but couldn't reach anything. I've Spring Boot app that has multiple Spring Batch jobs and I want to understand in what order job launcher is executing these multiple different jobs?

Comment: What do you mean? They are defined by time. Or are you talking about if they all had the same start time? I guess it would be whatever order they are stored in.

Comment: do you have `spring.batch.job.enabled=true` ? if you are letting boot decide, it might be any order. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41364220/how-to-run-spring-batch-jobs-in-certain-order-spring-boot/41437552#41437552) if that helps .

Comment: @SabirKhan yes i have it enabled, I've couple of jobs and I wanted to make sure that not one of them will take over the others since I use sync executor